# how to make 2 cloths collide with each other?

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I'm having a problem with a cloth simulation. I've set 2 planes up and applied a cloth modifier to each, what I want to happen is for the two cloths to fall together and interact with each other. The problem I'm having is that both objects are passing through each other. I have cloth collision turned on, and self collision too. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Picture here, as always, any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either merge the two objects into one object with self-collision cloth physics, or you can have two separate objects, each with its own cloth physics, but then both need to also have collision physics enabled.

For more explanation see the answer to this question: [How can I make sure that simulated cloth doesn't go through other objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44287/how-can-i-make-sure-that-simulated-cloth-doesnt-go-through-other-objects)

Comment: I attempted to do this with Blender 2.82 and with blocks as cloth. The first way (joining objects and turning on self-collisions) seems to exhibit better results according to my blend file. Details here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/how-to-make-cloth-catch-a-falling-object-slowing-its-fall/176006#176006

Answer (score 2):

Add a collision modifier to each plane after the cloth modifier.