# why collision is not working?

Tags: collision

[image]I am a total beginner in blender and I am trying to create a sofa and when I am trying to fall my blanket on the sofa edge even after using collision it's still clipping and I don't know what to do. Kindly help. I am adding some pictures for reference.[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out and help you.

Comment: Inside the cloth setting, under collision, you need to make adjustments to the quality and distance in order to have see a better result. In the case of quality, the more, the better but it's gonna make your simulation slower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make sure that simulated cloth doesn't go through other objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44287/how-can-i-make-sure-that-simulated-cloth-doesnt-go-through-other-objects)

Comment: not yet as it's still clipping @Emir

Comment: the blanket is clipping through the sofa base pillow and through side board